# Strange: why Django related many-to-many lookup works this way (but not like in docs)?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

The Django docs describe how to query reverse m2m fields: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352662/how-to-use-the-reverse-of-a-django-manytomany-relationship) we should use `related_name` as the first argument in the query.

But I'm having trouble making this work. (I'm using Django 1.8.5). Here are my example models:

```
class Nlpneutralfeature(models.Model):   
    neutral_feature = models.CharField(u'found word', max_length=255, default='')   

class Userproject(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="project", verbose_name=("owner"))
    monitoring_words = models.ManyToManyField(Nlpneutralfeature, null=True, blank=True, related_name="monitoringwords")        
    name = models.CharField(u'Название проекта', unique=True, max_length=255)
```

So, to get all `Nlpneutralfeature` rows that belong to `Userproject` where `Userproject.name == '48'`, I need to do:

```
Nlpneutralfeature.objects.filter(userproject__monitoringwords__name='48')
```

But this does not work. The error I get is: `Cannot resolve keyword *'userproject'* into field`.

So, Django cannot understand that *'userproject'* is lowercased model name Userproject.

Now, this is working:

```
Nlpneutralfeature.objects.filter(monitoringwords__name='48')
```

How does Django know that `monitoringwords` is `related_name`? No error is strange to me, sicne there is no `monitoringwords` field in the `Nlpneutralfeature` model!

Comment: I don't understand why you're confused. You explicitly defined the related_name, so that's what it uses instead of the lower case of the model.

Comment: And also I don't understand how that is not like the docs you link to; it's *exactly* like the docs.

Comment: look at "reverse relation"

Comment: What is your AUTH_USER_MODEL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the phrasing in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name):

> The name to user for the relation from the related object back to this one. It's also the default value for **related_query_name** (the name to use for the reverse filter name from the target model).

In your example, the "target model" is `Nlpneutralfeature`. When you set `related_name = 'monitoringwords'` on the ManyToManyField `Userproject.monitoringwords`, it tells Django to use that `related_name` to refer from `Nlpneutralfeature` model objects *back* to the corresponding `Userproject` model objects.

Correspondingly, if you had declared `Userproject.monitoringwords` with `related_name = 'foo'`, the way to query for all `Nlpneautralfeatures` belonging to project 48 would be: `Nlpneautralfeature.objects.filter(foo__name='48')`.

Answer (score 1):

the `related_name` here is so you can get your Userproject models related to an `Nlpneutralfeature` model.
eg:

```
nf = Nlpneutralfeature.objects.get(neutral_feature="XXX")
# From here you can get all Userprojects related to this nf like this:
userProjects = nf.monitoringwords.all()
```

if you didn't declared a related_name then you had to do it like this:

```
nf = Nlpneutralfeature.objects.get(neutral_feature="XXX")
# From here you can get all Userprojects related to this nf like this:
userProjects = nf.Userproject_set.all()
```

i think you understaned this property by inverse.. in my opinion i thing you should declare it here like this: `related_name="user_projects"`

in summary, related_name is to use when you want to get the current models(where you declare your M2M relationship) from the related model.